# Why does my program return a memory address?

Tags: c

I wrote a program called averageFloat which is supposed to take a scan input of a number. That allows a number of float inputs to be input by the user and then the function takes the average of these inputs.

However, when I compiled and ran the program it did take my input, but it returned -1610612736.

I've already tried changing the storage for scanf, I added a pointer and included global variables that scanf will call in the main function and the averageFloat function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float averageFloat(int a);

int y;
float z; 

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Please input a number of floats you want to include "); 
    n = scanf("%d", &y); 
    averageFloat(n);

    return 0;
}

float averageFloat(int a){

    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        printf("Please enter the float variables you want your program to average");
        scanf("%f", &z); 
        z += z;
    }
    printf("the average float is %d", z/a);
    return z / a; 
}
```

I expect this to take my input n, let's say n = 5.

I expect to be able to input 5 float numbers, let's say 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1 and 1.5 and then have that divide by n

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues in your code:

- Using `scanf` to write to the `z` variable which is also your
  summing variable. You are basically overwriting the total each time you read an input
- Scanning a decimal number into a floating point variable will unintended results. Need to change `scanf("%d",&z);` to `scanf("%f",&z);`
- The printf statement is expecting an integer and you are passing a pointer to a float. So need to change `printf("the average float is %d", z/a);` to `printf("the average float is %f", z/a);`
- The variable y needs to be passed to the `averageFloat` function, not the return value of the `scanf` function in the line before.

Comment: (voice of Megatron) Yeeess. . . I see. It's so clear now.

Comment: I noticed another problem playing around with it, when I add 2 inputs and then input 2.5 and 3.5 it returns 2.5 when it should return 3.0 why is this?

Comment: On closer inspection you are also using the return value of the scanf statement as the number of element to average:  `n = scanf("%d", &y);averageFloat(n);`. The variable y should be used  in the call to averageFloat

Comment: But shouldn't y and n basically be the same here, or am I missing something? ( I'm definitely missing something because I did what you said and it worked properly.)

Comment: No. The return value is the number of items scanned from the input. So `scanf("%f, %f, %f", &x,&y,&z)` will return 3 on success. The values actually captured from the input are in the variables x,y and z ( if the scan was successful).  Perhaps do a search for 'man scanf' to get the scanf manual page to get a better understanding.

Comment: So THAT'S why it kept returning 2.5 and that's why I have to use y, because the value it returns upon assignment is just the number of items. I'll just keep reading, I haven't gotten far enough in my book yet but there is a section on the limits of scanf later on.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `scanf("%f", &z);` you're destroying whatever value `z` had. You're also not checking whether the `scanf` was successful.

You should do something along the lines:

```
float zz= 0.0;
scanf("%f", &zz); 
z += zz;
```

Also, after you've finished, you could either do:

```
printf("the average float is %d", (int) z/a);
return z / a;
```

Or:

```
printf("the average float is %f", z/a);
return z / a;
```

The first truncating to `int` (`%d`) and the second printing a `float`.

You should also check that `a` is not zero.

You should also use:

```
averageFloat(y);
```

Comment: `(int)(z/a)` would be better since it preserves more information.

Comment: This worked, I chose the bottom method. Thank you! :) But I'm not clear on what happened. All I did was declare a global zz, and put a local variable z inside of averageFloat. Why did that fix everything?

Comment: 3 things: first, you were overwriting `z` with the `scanf`, so declaring a variable just to input the numbers is the right way (`zz`). Second, you were telling it that you were going to print an integer (`%d`), but you were giving it a float (the result of a division that included a float; there should be a warning about this on any modern compiler). Third, `n= scanf("%d", &y);` means: **put the number read in `y` and give me success indicator on `n`**, so if you input 3, `y` will have 3 and `n` will have 1.

Comment: @paxdiablo No. `(int)(z/a)` truncates the fractional part.

Comment: Mirko, my intent was to defer the truncation as long as possible since `(int) z / a` truncates `z` *then* does integer division while `(int)(z/a)` does the division as a float and only truncates the float value afterwards. However, on testing it, I couldn't come up with an example that had a difference since truncation rounds toward zero. I suspect rounding would be a different matter.

Comment: @paxdiablo Noted. I though you meant that it was better than the `float` alternative. Anyway, I think that as long as `a` is integer, it doesn't matter whetter you do `((int)z)/a` or `(int)(z/a)` (*maybe* first form does integer division and the latter does float division, then rounding).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, variables shouldn't be global. Secondly, you add to z then you read it.
And you probably mean to call the function averageFloat(y).